# Envers & "A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session"

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-envers

I'm trying to use envers in my hibernate 5 project in order to monitor changes in DB. But I'm facing an issue with `@Embeddable` elements.

When I'm saving Entities that contain `@Embeddable` elements, I get the following error: `Caused by: javax.persistence.EntityExistsException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [entity_embedded_entity_AUD#{SETORDINAL=1, REV=com.bl.dpi.appli.example.hibernate.envers.audited.revision.UpperRevisionObject@7a814310, AuditedEntityWithEmedded_id=d9b141ce-5ac1-4209-969e-8229845dd606, REVTYPE=ADD}]`

I've tried many thins to resolve this (stackoverflow FTW!) but without succes

Here are my classes

EmbeddableEntity.class

```
@Embeddable
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Getter
@Setter
public class EmbeddableEntity {
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "text")
    private String text;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "value")
    private Float value;
}
```

AuditedEntityWithEmedded.class

```
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Table(name = "AuditedEntityWithEmedded")
@Audited
public class AuditedEntityWithEmedded {

    public AuditedEntityWithEmedded() {
        this(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    }

    public AuditedEntityWithEmedded(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Id
    @NotNull
    private final String id;

    @Column
    private String nom;

    @ElementCollection(targetClass = EmbeddableEntity.class)
    @CollectionTable(name = "entity_embedded_entity", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "AuditedEntityWithEmedded_id"))
    private List<EmbeddableEntity> embeddedList;
}
```

And my test class: AuditedEntityWithEmeddedTest.class

```
public class AuditedEntityWithEmeddedTest extends AbstractAuditedTest<AuditedEntityWithEmedded, String> {

    @Autowired
    private JpaRepository<AuditedEntityWithEmedded, String> repo;

    private static final String nom10 = "1.0";

    private static final String TEXT0 = "Text0";
    private static final String TEXT1 = "Text1";
    private static final Float VAL0 = 0f;
    private static final Float VAL1 = 1f;

    @Test
    public void saveEntity() {
        AuditedEntityWithEmedded auditedEntityWithEmedded = new AuditedEntityWithEmedded();
        auditedEntityWithEmedded.setNom(nom10);
        auditedEntityWithEmedded.setEmbeddedList(createEmbeddableList());

        repo.save(auditedEntityWithEmedded);
    }

    private List<EmbeddableEntity> createEmbeddableList() {
        ArrayList<EmbeddableEntity> list = new ArrayList<EmbeddableEntity>();

        list.add(new EmbeddableEntity(TEXT0, VAL0));
        list.add(new EmbeddableEntity(TEXT1, VAL1));

        return list;
    }
}
```

When I run the test class I get the following exception:

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [entity_embedded_entity_AUD#{SETORDINAL=1, REV=com.bl.dpi.appli.example.hibernate.envers.audited.revision.UpperRevisionObject@375084c9, AuditedEntityWithEmedded_id=d773bace-a59e-46ac-833a-53d8210f21bd, REVTYPE=ADD}]; nested exception is javax.persistence.EntityExistsException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [entity_embedded_entity_AUD#{SETORDINAL=1, REV=com.bl.dpi.appli.example.hibernate.envers.audited.revision.UpperRevisionObject@375084c9, AuditedEntityWithEmedded_id=d773bace-a59e-46ac-833a-53d8210f21bd, REVTYPE=ADD}]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:410)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:246)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:521)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:761)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:504)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:292)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy103.save(Unknown Source)
    at com.bl.dpi.appli.example.hibernate.envers.embedded.AuditedEntityWithEmeddedTest.saveEntity(AuditedEntityWithEmeddedTest.java:38)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: javax.persistence.EntityExistsException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [entity_embedded_entity_AUD#{SETORDINAL=1, REV=com.bl.dpi.appli.example.hibernate.envers.audited.revision.UpperRevisionObject@375084c9, AuditedEntityWithEmedded_id=d773bace-a59e-46ac-833a-53d8210f21bd, REVTYPE=ADD}]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:116)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convertCommitException(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:71)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:517)
    ... 48 more
```

Does someone have an idea? (I've already tested and readed similar posts on stackoverflow)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, adding `@OrderColumn` seems to resolve the exception

```
public class AuditedEntityWithEmedded {

    public AuditedEntityWithEmedded() {
        this(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    }

    public AuditedEntityWithEmedded(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Id
    @NotNull
    private final String id;

    @Column
    private String nom;


    @ElementCollection(targetClass = EmbeddableEntity.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "entity_embedded_entity", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "AuditedEntityWithEmedded_id"))
    @OrderColumn // <--- HERE
    private List<EmbeddableEntity> embeddedList;
}
```

Comment: Change the `List` to a `Set` and you shouldn't have to apply the `@OrderColumn` annotation to fix the issue.  The problem is that the ordinal position isn't pushed into the PK from what I recall unless the container is of type `Set`.

Comment: Hi @Jerem , on any record modification of embedded entity does envers storing proper audit , i am getting 2 entry on update instead of one for revtype =1 , it stores 2records one with revtype=0 and other revtype=2 . I have same scenario as this question